# How to parse name and email in GAS

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

the function GmailApp.getMessageById("1405...8").getFrom() will return name and email in two different cases, afaik:

```
"Full Name <email@domain.com>"
"email@domain.com"
```

I need to parse Name and Email in either case, and so far this is the best I have found ...

```
function getFrom_(namemail) { // assuming namemail always contains a valid email (name <email> or just email)
  var from = {};
  from.email = namemail.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi)[0];
  from.name = namemail.replace(from.email, "").replace("<>", "").trim();
  return from;
}
```

Any better way?

Regards, Fausto

Answer (score 1):

You might want to see if the getReplyTo function works better for you:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getReplyTo()

In my testing, the string returned was empty because the replyTo was not set I assume, so YMMV. I think it's only putting the Full Name and <> if the contact is in your contacts list, and was seeing the sender's e-mail without the Full Name for e-mails where I did not have the contact data

Comment: getReplyTo function only returns an email if it's been setup within gmail settings as such, while getFrom always returns a value in those two formats I mentioned (name <email> OR email)